# unmanaged vps centos6.4 need to open port 20/21

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, vps

I brought an unmanaged vps which is running Centos 6.4 and the only port which was open was 22. I to open ports 20 and 21 so I can ftp, but every time I try to it won't save and let me login thru filezilla.

**any suggestions?**

**EDIT:** This is what I've done

```
[root@itsonlyme ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp-data
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp-data
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp-data
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp ctstate    NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 21 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp-data ct   state RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 20 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535    dpts:1024:65535 ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Allow passive inbound connections */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-ho   st-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp ctstate    NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 21 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp-data ct   state ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 20 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535    dpts:1024:65535 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* Allow passive inbound connection   s */
[root@itsonlyme ~]# iptables --line -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     5167  757K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        3   134 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4      129  7628 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
5        8   404 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:20
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
8        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:20
9        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:20
11     211 24114 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
12       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port    21 */
13       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on    port 20 */
14       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:1024:65535 ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Allow passive inbound connections */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4994 packets, 895K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port    21 */
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20 ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 20    */
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:1024:65535 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /*    Allow passive inbound connections */
[root@itsonlyme ~]# service iptables restart
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Loading additional modules: ip_conntrack_ftp     [  OK  ]

[root@itsonlyme ~]# reboot

Broadcast message from root@itsonlyme
        (/dev/pts/0) at 6:37 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
```

Then I did this

```
[root@itsonlyme ~]#
login as: root
[root@itsonlyme ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
# Load additional iptables modules (nat helpers)
#   Default: -none-
# Space separated list of nat helpers (e.g. 'ip_nat_ftp ip_nat_irc'), which
# are loaded after the firewall rules are applied. Options for the helpers are
# stored in /etc/modprobe.conf.
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"

# Unload modules on restart and stop
#   Value: yes|no,  default: yes
# This option has to be 'yes' to get to a sane state for a firewall
# restart or stop. Only set to 'no' if there are problems unloading netfilter
# modules.
IPTABLES_MODULES_UNLOAD="yes"

# Save current firewall rules on stop.
#   Value: yes|no,  default: no
# Saves all firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables if firewall gets stopped
# (e.g. on system shutdown).
IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP="yes"

# Save current firewall rules on restart.
#   Value: yes|no,  default: no
# Saves all firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables if firewall gets
# restarted.
IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART="yes"

# Save (and restore) rule and chain counter.
#   Value: yes|no,  default: no
# Save counters for rules and chains to /etc/sysconfig/iptables if
# 'service iptables save' is called or on stop or restart if SAVE_ON_STOP or
# SAVE_ON_RESTART is enabled.
IPTABLES_SAVE_COUNTER="no"

# Numeric status output
#   Value: yes|no,  default: yes
# Print IP addresses and port numbers in numeric format in the status output.
IPTABLES_STATUS_NUMERIC="yes"

# Verbose status output
#   Value: yes|no,  default: yes
# Print info about the number of packets and bytes plus the "input-" and
# "outputdevice" in the status output.
IPTABLES_STATUS_VERBOSE="no"

# Status output with numbered lines
"/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config" 54L, 1992C
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. I know this isn't part of your question, but... **Update your system. 6.4 is WAY too old and you're bound to get owned.**
2. You more than likely need to go to /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config and modify the `IPTABLES_MODULES=""` directive. Be sure to take care of the other modules that are being loaded when you add it.

   `IPTABLES_MODULES="... ip_conntrack_ftp"`
3. Next thing, you probably should modify the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file manually. And right before the "DROP" or "REJECT" line, put something like... `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT` for both of your ports, and then restart iptables.

Also, next time, please use **text** when presenting your problem. That screenshot is too small for anyone viewing your question.